# Carriage return on button

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

How can I add a carriage return on the label below after `Submit` and before `abs($model->total)`?

This is a yii bootstrap button.  I have tried combos of `\n\r` and `<br />` put those just appear in the button then...tried with using both `""` and `''`

```
 $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton',array(
        'htmlOptions' => array('class'=>'btn'),
        'label' => 'Submit'.abs($model->total),
        'url' => array('/myPage'),
    ))
```

;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set this to false

```
encodeLabel boolean true    Whether the label should be encoded.
```

Comment: Thats it, put `'encodeLabel'=>false,` I will accept when it allows me to